# Interrelated columns in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

To keep track of cash flow I have a number of interrelated columns in a data.table:

- "Amount_spent" is always 5% of the "Balance".
- "Revenue" is "Amount_spent" * "Price"
- "Balance" is the cumulative sum of "Revenue" (starting at 100.00).
- Transactions only happen on "Day" "a"

I am struggling to calculate these interrelated columns concurrently.
Example as I would like:

```
library(data.table)
Day <- c( "a", "c", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a" )
Price <- c( 0.6, 0.4, 0.9, -0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9, -0.7 )
Balance <- c( 100.00, 103.00, 103.00, 103.00, 101.46, 101.46, 102.47, 102.47, 102.47, 107.08 )
Amount_spent <- c( 5.00, 0.00, 0.00, 5.15, 0.00, 5.07, 0.00, 0.00, 5.12, 5.35 )
Revenue <- c( 3.00, 0.00, 0.00, -1.55, 0.00, 1.01, 0.00, 0.00, 4.61, -3.75 )

DT <- data.table( Day, Price, Balance, Amount_spent, Revenue )
DT
```

Here is my attempt so far:

```
# set initial balance
Balance2 <- 100.00
Day2 <- c( "a", "c", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a" )
Price2 <- c( 0.6, 0.4, 0.9, -0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9, -0.7 )
my.try <- data.table( Day2, Price2 )
my.try[, Balance2 := cumsum( Revenue2 )]
my.try[ Day2 == "a", Amount_spent2 := Balance2 * 0.05 ]
my.try[is.na(Amount_spent2), Amount_spent2 := 0]
my.try[, Revenue2 := Price2 * Amount_spent2 ]
my.try
```

As you will see it fails with this error message `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Revenue2' not found` as the "Revenue2" column is yet to be created.

Thank you

Comment: why not to use `my.try[is.na(Amount_spent2), Amount_spent2  := 0]` and not use `<-` against data.table column (bad practice), also drop `na.zero` function at all.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my code

Comment: @jangorecki thanks for the advice. Any thoughts on how to  calculate the columns concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

You get mentioned error after the line `my.try[, Balance2 := cumsum( Revenue2 )]` which try to use the column `Revenue2` which not exist in `DT` at that point in the code.

```
library(data.table)
Day <- c( "a", "c", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a" )
Price <- c( 0.6, 0.4, 0.9, -0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9, -0.7 )
Balance <- c( 100.00, 103.00, 103.00, 103.00, 101.46, 101.46, 102.47, 102.47, 102.47, 107.08 )
Amount_spent <- c( 5.00, 0.00, 0.00, 5.15, 0.00, 5.07, 0.00, 0.00, 5.12, 5.35 )
Revenue <- c( 3.00, 0.00, 0.00, -1.55, 0.00, 1.01, 0.00, 0.00, 4.61, -3.75 )

DT <- data.table( Day, Price, Balance, Amount_spent, Revenue )

Balance2 <- 100.00
Day2 <- c( "a", "c", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a" )
Price2 <- c( 0.6, 0.4, 0.9, -0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9, -0.7 )
my.try <- data.table( Day2, Price2 )
my.try[, Balance2 := cumsum( Revenue2 )]
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Revenue2' not found
"Revenue2" %in% names(DT)
#[1] FALSE
```

You did not produce expected results. I'm not sure what you mean by *calculate the columns concurrently*. If you want to assign/update multiple columns by reference in a single step you can use `` `:=()` `` function the same way as you would use `.()` or `list()` in data.table's `j` argument. For example: `` `:=`(col1=1+2, col2=2+3) ``.
You can read more about *update by reference* in [Reference semantics vignette](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html).

Comment: Thanks @jangorecki . I will read the vignette as that is what I need to do; 'assign/update multiple columns by reference in a single step'. I need each column to update simultaneously so that I have a data.table the same as DT in my first example.

Comment: I read the vignette and I could update my code to `my.try[, c( "Balance2", "Revenue2", "Amount_spent2" ) := list( cumsum( Revenue2 ), Price2 * Amount_spent2, Balance2 * 0.05 )]` for efficiency however I still get the same issue. Each value is dependant on the result of values in the other columns.

Comment: @user3740289 you are referring a `Balance2` column which was not yet evaluated. Split it into two steps, when doing both with `:=` it will still be very fast. You can chain `[` data.table calls: `my.try[, c( "Balance2") := cumsum( Revenue2 )][, c("Revenue2", "Amount_spent2" ) := list(Price2 * Amount_spent2, Balance2 * 0.05 )]`

Comment: Thanks @jangorecki but I still get the error message `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Revenue2' not found` . Is there perhaps a way to create each column first, then loop through and update each value?

Comment: @user3740289 IMO you should rethink the formulas for you measures, they depends on each other.

Comment: This didn't quite answer my question so I have simplified my example and asked a new question here [Interdependent columns in R data.table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402566/interdependent-columns-in-r-data-table)