# Recursive update of columns in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

As a simple example I need to create the following table (this is my desired result):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table( A= c(2,5,4,-2,4), 
                  B= c(1000,1100,1375,1650,1485), 
                  C= c(50,55,68.75,82.5,74.25), 
                  D= c(100,275,275,-165,297))
DT
```

This is my attempt so far which is not working:

```
DT.2 <- data.table(A= c(2,5,4,-2,4) )
DT.2[, B := 1000 ]  # B should begin at 1000, then cumulatively add column D
DT.2[, C := B * 0.05 ]  
DT.2[, D := A * C ]  
DT.2[, B := 1000 + cumsum(shift(D, type= "lag", fill=FALSE)) ]
DT.2
```

As you can see the columns do not update correctly as each column relies on the results of other columns. It's a very easy calculation in Excel and I just need to understand how to adapt it to R. 
Thank you

Comment: This is weirdly recursive -- you initialize `B` to  as `1000`. Then `C` depends on `B`, `D` depends on `C`, and `B` is redefined to depend on `D`. Seems circular.

Comment: Can you explain how to obtain your desired results (i.e. what transformation is applied)?

Comment: I created the example in Excel. Column B starts at 1000 then relies on the results of other columns. I can imagine it requires a loop function or the apply family, but I cant make it happen.

Comment: @fishtank what do you mean by transformation?

Comment: Please, explain clearly what you are trying to do. What kind of operations you want to perform on your dataset? Provide also the desired output.

Comment: I think I understand. Only the first row is defined exogenously. The rest follows form the first row.

Comment: I think you're right, the first row of `B` and the whole `A` column are inputs.

Comment: I would like to create the data.table 'DT' as in my first example above. To do this I need column B to begin as 1000, it will then cumulatively add column D. Column C is a product of column B * 0.05. Column D is the product of A * C. In reality this is a data table used to keep track of financial balance which varies over time with expenditure and incomings. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So far as I can tell, you need a loop. Here's my input data:

```
DT <- data.table(A = c(2, 5, 4, -2, 4),
                 B = c(1000, rep(NA, 4)),
                 C = numeric(5),
                 D = numeric(5))
```

And the loop I use:

```
#initial row
DT[1, c("C", "D") := .(.05 * B, .05 * A * B)]

#subsequent rows
for (nn in 2:nrow(DT)){
  new_B <- DT[nn - 1L, B + D]
  DT[nn, c("B", "C", "D") := .(new_B, .05 * new_B, .05 * A * new_B)]
}
```

Could also easily be translated to a `sapply` so you don't have `nn` sitting around in your namespace (but now it will print something meaningless to your console):

```
sapply(2:nrow(DT), function(nn){
  (same as before)})
```

And yes, I can imagine this would look much simpler in Excel since it auto-updates the formula for you with click+drag.

Comment: Yes @MichaelChirico that is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much! For me to understand this a little better how should I have worded the question better? ie. if I were to search for this type of application on-line what would I look for?

Comment: @user3740289 I think giving your "initial" data as I did in my answer would have been less confusing to readers -- much clearer what's going on once you realize you only know `B[1]` _ex ante_. Other than that, perhaps a clearer understanding on your part of exactly how the columns are generated (not _interdependently_ but _recursively_), or else a clearer explication of the method.

Comment: @user3740289 I agree with Michael. I think several people missed the fact that you *led* with your desired result --- it's more common to see that at the end of the question. And a big second on being clear about the inputs. When you show `B := 1000` it sets **every row** of `B` to 1000, but you only wanted the first row set to 1000.

Comment: Ok yes that makes sense. I really appreciate the answer and these recommendations. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think that you actually want a function, and I am guessing that it would make more sense like this:

```
fun <- function(id, ## not sure what this is, probably an id
                start = 1000, 
                rate = .05,
                gain_or_loss){
    require(data.table)

    cnt <- length(id)
    ret <- data.table(ID = c(id, NA),
                      bal = cumsum(c(start, gain_or_loss)),
                      fixed_change = rep(NA_real_, cnt + 1),
                      total_change = c(gain_or_loss, NA_real_))
    ret[ , fixed_change := bal * 0.05 ]  
    ret <- ret[] ## needed because of a data.table quirk
    return(ret)
}
```

Which would give:

```
fun(id = c(2,5,4,-2,4),
    gain_or_loss = c(100,275,275,-165,297))

#    ID  bal fixed_change total_change
# 1:  2 1000        50.00          100
# 2:  5 1100        55.00          275
# 3:  4 1375        68.75          275
# 4: -2 1650        82.50         -165
# 5:  4 1485        74.25          297
# 6: NA 1782        89.10           NA
```

I would also add code after `require` to say `if (length(id) != length(gain_or_loss)) stop("id and gain_or_loss need to be of the same length")`

Comment: Thanks @geneorama, I'm testing each option now.

Comment: My main point is that the question becomes easier with more descriptive variable names, and the answer become easier when you use a function.